# the accuracy of A vs. A is indeed accurate

Tags: comparative-constructions

First of all, I wanna thank everyone here and I felt so fortunate to find this wonderful forum.

Here is my question. What's the difference between the sentences below in terms of implications and tones?

1. I will be able to determine that this article is indeed accurate.
2. I will be able to determine the accuracy of this article.

Many thanks,

Leon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first implies that you already believe the article is accurate and you will be able to show that.  I would say, however, that *show* is a better fit than *determine* if this is your desired meaning.  *Determine* carries a nuance that contradicts your conviction.  Consider the following examples:

1. I will be able to determine that I do, indeed, live in the United States.
2. I will be able to show that I do, indeed, live in the United States.

The first seems to say that I firmly believe I live in the US, but I don't exactly know how I know that.

Your second statement carries no similar implication as your first.  The article may be accurate or may be inaccurate.  You will be able to determine which.